# How to create separate plots in different windows that don't interfere with each other?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This my first time using gui in python so sorry if my code is not pretty.

What I am doing is showing three signals of human body generated by the neurokit2 library (ecg, emg,rsp). I succeeded in showing the signal as it progress with time using matplotlib animation (it has a lot of flaws but I think I can fix them if I searched long enough). What I am truly struggling with for days now is that I need to show a spectrogram of the three signals (not animated though just a static graph).

But each time I try to show the spectrogram, it interferes with the plot of the animation producing garbage graphs and freezes the program.

So how can I totally separate these two functions from each other and produce different windows for each function?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import neurokit2 as nk
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.backends._backend_tk import Toolbar, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


class Toolbar(NavigationToolbar2Tk):
    # only display the buttons we need
    toolitems = [t for t in NavigationToolbar2Tk.toolitems if
                 t[0] in ('Home', 'Pan', 'Zoom')]

    # t[0] in ('Home', 'Pan', 'Zoom','Save')]

    def _init_(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Toolbar, self)._init_(*args, **kwargs)


def draw_figure(canvas, figure, canvas_toolbar=None):
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw_idle()
    if canvas_toolbar is not None:
        toolbar = Toolbar(figure_canvas_agg, canvas_toolbar)
        toolbar.update()
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
    return figure_canvas_agg


def main():
    # define the form layout
    layout = [[sg.Text('Signal Viewer', size=(40, 1), justification='center', font='Helvetica 20')],
              [sg.Canvas(key='controls_cv', pad=((280, 0), 3))],
              [sg.Canvas(size=(50, 36), key='-CANVAS-'), sg.Canvas(size=(50, 36), key='-CANVAS0-')],
              [sg.Button('ECG', pad=((250, 0), 3)), sg.Button('EMG'), sg.Button('RSP'), sg.Button('Spec')],
              [sg.Button('Exit', size=(5, 1), pad=((280, 0), 3), font='Helvetica 14')]]

    # create the form and show it without the plot
    window = sg.Window('Signal Viewer', layout, finalize=True)

    canvas_elem = window['-CANVAS-']
    canvas2_e = window['-CANVAS0-']
    canvas = canvas_elem.TKCanvas
    canvas2 = canvas2_e.TKCanvas
    x, y = [], []
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
    plt.grid(True)
    fig_agg = draw_figure(canvas, fig, window.FindElement('controls_cv').TKCanvas)
    fig_agg2 = draw_figure(canvas2, fig2)

    def wave2(ecg100):
        plt.specgram(ecg100, NFFT=64, Fs=256, noverlap=32)
        fig_agg2.draw_idle()

    def wave_form(ecg100):
        def update_time():
            t = 0
            t_max = len(ecg100)
            while t < t_max and t >= 0:
                t += ani.direction
                yield t

        def animate(frame):
            st, end = frame / 2, frame + 0.5
            x.append(ecg100[frame])
            plt.cla()
            plt.ylim([ecg100.min(), ecg100.max()])
            plt.plot(x)
            plt.grid()
            plt.tight_layout()
            ax.set_xlim(st, end)

        def on_press(event1):
            print(event1.key)
            if event1.key.isspace():
                if ani.running:
                    ani.event_source.stop()
                else:
                    ani.event_source.start()
                ani.running ^= True
            elif event1.key == 'left':
                ani.direction = -1
            elif event1.key == 'right':
                ani.direction = +1
            if event1.key in ['left', 'right']:
                t = ani.frame_seq.__next__()
                animate(t)

        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_press)
        ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, frames=update_time(), interval=5, repeat=True)
        ani.running = True
        ani.direction = +1
        fig_agg.draw_idle()

    while True:
        event, values = window.read(timeout=10)
        if event in ('Exit', sg.WIN_CLOSED):
            exit(69)
        elif event in 'ECG':
            ecg100 = nk.ecg_simulate(duration=10, noise=0.01, heart_rate=100)
            wave_form(ecg100)
            wave2(ecg100)
        elif event in 'EMG':
            ecg100 = nk.emg_simulate(duration=10, sampling_rate=100, burst_number=4)
            wave_form(ecg100)
            wave2(ecg100)
        elif event in 'RSP':
            ecg100 = nk.rsp_simulate(duration=30, sampling_rate=50, noise=0.01)
            wave_form(ecg100)
            wave2(ecg100)
    window.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The funtion wave2 is the function that I want to implement for the signal to produce spectrogram in different plot when I press the 'spec' button

[image: this is the gui now]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User code cannot run on my platform, so just example here.
Of course, you can use `sg.Canvas` here.

```py
import math

from matplotlib import use as use_agg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def pack_figure(graph, figure):
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, graph.Widget)
    plot_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
    plot_widget.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
    return plot_widget

def plot_figure(index, theta):
    fig = plt.figure(index)         # Active an existing figure
    ax = plt.gca()                  # Get the current axes
    x = [degree for degree in range(1080)]
    y = [math.sin((degree+theta)/180*math.pi) for degree in range(1080)]
    ax.cla()                        # Clear the current axes
    ax.set_title(f"Sensor Data {index}")
    ax.set_xlabel("X axis")
    ax.set_ylabel("Y axis")
    ax.set_xscale('log')
    ax.grid()
    plt.plot(x, y)                  # Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers
    fig.canvas.draw()               # Rendor figure into canvas

# Use Tkinter Agg
use_agg('TkAgg')

layout = [[sg.Graph((640, 480), (0, 0), (640, 480), key='Graph1'), sg.Graph((640, 480), (0, 0), (640, 480), key='Graph2')]]
window = sg.Window('Matplotlib', layout, finalize=True)


# Initial
graph1 = window['Graph1']
graph2 = window['Graph2']
plt.ioff()                          # Turn the interactive mode off
fig1 = plt.figure(1)                # Create a new figure
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)              # Add a subplot to the current figure.
fig2 = plt.figure(2)                # Create a new figure
ax2 = plt.subplot(111)              # Add a subplot to the current figure.
pack_figure(graph1, fig1)           # Pack figure under graph
pack_figure(graph2, fig2)
theta1 = 0                          # theta for fig1
theta2 = 90                         # theta for fig2
plot_figure(1, theta1)
plot_figure(2, theta2)

while True:

    event, values = window.read(timeout=10)

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT:
        theta1 = (theta1 + 40) % 360
        plot_figure(1, theta1)
        theta2 = (theta2 + 40) % 260
        plot_figure(2, theta2)

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. it's not exactly what i want but it helped me greatly.